# django custom user model referencing to groups and permissions

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have made a custom User model..

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
    help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters'),
    validators=[
        validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'), _('Enter a valid username.'), _('invalid'))
    ])

    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=255)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'))

    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))

    '''
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True, help_text=_('The groups this user belongs to. A user will '
        'get all permissions granted to each of '
        'his/her group.'),
        related_name="tmp_user_set", related_query_name="user")

    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission,
        verbose_name=_('user permissions'), blank=True,
        help_text=_('Specific permissions for this user.'),
        related_name="tmp_user_set", related_query_name="user")
    '''



    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email',]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

Here when I reference groups to Group and user_permissions to Permission it gives error. How can I get these groups and permissions when I add it from admin side.

And when I make another model like Hospital and Inherit it from User like Hospital(User) then can I get the field of User in Hospital.

Any help ??

Comment: Local field 'groups' in class 'User' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'PermissionsMixin'

Comment: And, why you just not change the member name, lets say to groups_ or _groups?

Comment: I did I changed it to groupss and user_permissionss.. adding extra 's'. It says the same error

Comment: PermissionsMixin already implements what you are trying to create:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/059f5d17c5fe92d6b4c5d189020ea59e9bed4472/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L307 so why are you trying to re-introduce those fields?

Comment: Ohk got it then how can I include groups and user_permission field in admin side when I add user ??

Comment: Got the solution.. Just had to registered fields in forms..